# Retrieve Data from an API

Tags: json, api

I'm using an api in my browser similar to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users. The data returned is JSON in the exact same format.

The difference is that my api receives search parameters in brackets

url.com/search?type=XXXXX&q=[**parameter**]&limit=10000&locale=en_US

Has anyone come across a parameter that will retrieve all JSON from an api? I don't know if this possible to do..

So far I've tried passing: [all], [get], [""], [ ], []

Comment: can you please be more specific?

Comment: sure, I will clarify in this edit

Comment: what exactly you're trying to achieve with this? why do you need a bracket for the q parameter?

Comment: I just want to retrieve everything from the api to count the records. That is how the api is displayed in my tutorial. What do you recommend?

Comment: you don't need to use any brackets @nate

Answer (score 0):

hello the way I get it is as follows. you must create a database or an array as you want then make the following call. in my case i use one database.

importar  json
solicitudes de importación
importar  psycopg2

r  =  requests . get ( 'AppiURL' )
datajson  =  r . json ()

## conexión a la base de datos

prueba :
conn  =  psycopg2 . connect ( "dbname = '' user = 'tu_usuari' host = 'localhost' password = 'tu_pswd'" )
except :
print  "No puedo conectarme a la base de datos"

cursor  =  conn . cursor ()
cursor . executemany ( "INSERTAR en yourdatabasetable (Row1,Row2,row3) VALUES (% (id) s,% (paramname1) s,% (paramname2) s,......)" , dataJson [ 'somename' ])
conn . commit ()
cursor . cerrar ()